# In which MS word version the formula representation in MathML is included?

Tags: ms-word

I want to know that when the representation of Mathematical formula(in OMML) in MS Word has been changed? How they were presenting previously?

Can anyone help me to know in which version of MS word the formula representation in OMML(result into MathML) has included?

Comment: Office 2007 introduced all of the open XML formats, but office 2003 should have updates to support them

Comment: Thank you Slai, I could find same on other blogs too. Do you have link/guide where Microsoft has officially declared this ? I am not able to find it.